# Error: Package exports for '/app/node_modules/uuid' do not define a valid '.' target

Tags: javascript, node.js

So some ungodly reason when I implement the following snippet:

```
import { Listener, OrderCreatedEvent, Subjects } from '@dc_microurb/common';
import { Message } from 'node-nats-streaming';
import { queueGroupName } from './queue-group-name';
import { expirationQueue } from '../../queues/expiration-queue';

export class OrderCreatedListener extends Listener<OrderCreatedEvent> {
  subject: Subjects.OrderCreated = Subjects.OrderCreated;
  queueGroupName = queueGroupName;

  async onMessage(data: OrderCreatedEvent['data'], msg: Message) {
    const delay = new Date(data.expiresAt).getTime() - new Date().getTime();
    console.log('Waiting this many milliseconds to process the job:', delay);

    await expirationQueue.add(
      {
        orderId: data.id,
      },
      {
        delay,
      }
    );

    msg.ack();
  }
}
```

In particular the first argument to `expirationQueue.add()`, `{orderId: data.id, }`, I get the following error in my terminal:

> [expiration-depl-5c47c7f4d5-5d68l expiration] Error: Package exports
> for '/app/node_modules/uuid' do not define a valid '.' target
> [expiration-depl-5c47c7f4d5-5d68l expiration]     at
> resolveExportsTarget (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:545:13)
> [expiration-depl-5c47c7f4d5-5d68l expiration]     at applyExports
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:459:14)
> [expiration-depl-5c47c7f4d5-5d68l expiration]     at resolveExports
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:508:12)
> [expiration-depl-5c47c7f4d5-5d68l expiration]     at
> Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:577:20)
> [expiration-depl-5c47c7f4d5-5d68l expiration]     at
> Function.Module._resolveFilename
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:27)
> [expiration-depl-5c47c7f4d5-5d68l expiration]     at
> Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:785:27)
> [expiration-depl-5c47c7f4d5-5d68l expiration]     at Module.require
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:956:19)
> [expiration-depl-5c47c7f4d5-5d68l expiration]     at require
> (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
> [expiration-depl-5c47c7f4d5-5d68l expiration]     at
> Object. (/app/node_modules/bull/lib/timer-manager.js:4:14)
> [expiration-depl-5c47c7f4d5-5d68l expiration]     at Module._compile
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
> [expiration-depl-5c47c7f4d5-5d68l expiration] [nodemon] app crashed -
> waiting for file changes before starting...

I upgraded my Node version to `v14.16.1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a Node issue.

It has [already happen](https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid/issues/466) in the past with `uuid`.
An [issue](https://github.com/nodejs/modules/issues/446) regarding node v13 also have been opened back then, to report a similar problem.

Even tho it's not a durable solution, try downgrading your Node version and open a ticket on the `uuid` Github repository.

Comment: I am not using Node v13, I am using the latest LTS.

Comment: @Daniel what I meant was: the problem occurred with v13 so no reasons for it to not occur with LTS.